# Django: Matching query does not exist and django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I had a fully working app on SQLite, now for production I had to configure it to use MySQL. I installed MySQL and the python client, changed my settings.py to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

So now when I run the server the admin part of the site is working fine, but when I try to login into the actual site I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /logins/
CustomUser matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/logins/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
CustomUser matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 307
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

I wanted to check if this column exists in my database, so in the terminal I went into the python shell and typed `from logins.models import *` and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "logins/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 88, in connect
    if settings.DEBUG:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

The thing is that besides the database I didn't touch any files in my project. I also still have the SQLite version of the app, and I tried running `from logins.models import *` from the python shell and I get the same error now as with MySQL. And before, as I mentioned, everything was working absolutely fine.

I would really appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Code for views.py login:

```
@login_required()
def index(request):
    u = request.user
    custom_user = CustomUser.objects.get(user=u)
    info_list =Info.objects.filter(game__in=custom_user.game.all(), department__in = custom_user.department.all()).distinct()
    #visible = Info.objects.filter(department__in=customuser.departments.all(), game__in=customuser.games.all())
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'info_list': info_list,
    })
    template = loader.get_template('logins/index.html')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['index'] = Info.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context), args)
```

Comment: Did you syncdb after making your changes?

Comment: @IanClark yes, I did
still the same query error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding the `ImproperlyConfigured` exception, Are you executing the `from logins.models import *` command form raw python shell, or django shell ?

   Make sure you are starting the shell using `./manage.py shell`, and then executing the above command
2. Regarding the `DoesNotExist` exception, it seems to be a problem with the login code. This exception normally occurs when a requested data does not exist in the table, and that situation is not handled in the code. It does not have to do anything with the table columns.

   Please paste the code behind */logins/* in the question for further comments.

Comment: ohh, that is such a dumb mistake of mine! you are right, I used python instead of django shell. My bad. Thanks for catching that. 
And regarding the DoesNotExist, I edited my question and posted the code for logins

Comment: The error seems to be coming from line `custom_user = CustomUser.objects.get(user=u)`. I don't think there is any need for this. `custom_user = request.user` should do the job instead. Also refer [Custom User Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)